# Accessing a specific element from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Morning, I have some HTML like this:

```
<ul class="Menu1">
    <li>I1</li>
    <li>I2</li>
</ul>
<ul class="Menu2">
    <li>I3</li>
    <li>I4</li>
</ul>
```

I want to access all the `li` from a specific `ul` (Menu 2 for example).
Sorry, I know this is really basic but what am I supposed to use instead of `$("li")` ?

Comment: Remove the space from the `class` attribute, then use `$('.Menu2 li')`

Comment: *"Sorry, I know this is really basic "* So do your research.

Comment: Note that `class="Menu 2"` defines an element with two distinct classes: `Menu` and `2`.

Comment: But with `$('.Menu2 li')` Menu2 isn't supposed to be the li class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF the `Menu` and `2` are ***2 separate class*** you can go with -

```
$('.Menu.2 li')
```

IF the `Menu` and `2` are ***1 class*** that is `Menu2` you can go with -

```
$('.Menu2 li')
```

Comment: No it's one classe i just made a space to better show the differences but  i didn't knew with a space we could have multiple casses. So i learned something at least^^
So yes i tesed it and it's woking thanks.

Comment: @Minirock Glad I could help and one more thing it's better to use small letters in `class` and `ID` - `ID attributes and class names are case sensitive`. It is legal to use them but it won't match the CSS selector .menu2 (it has to be .Menu2). Also, document.getElementById(".menu2") won't match.So always work with small letters in `HTML` its best to practise like that. ty

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do as per told by – @Rory McCrossan or You Have Distinct Class Name

1 And 2 
So, You Can Use

```
$('.2 li')
```

This Should Work